# how to remove an item from my context menu?

Tags: firefox, menu, debug

I installed a program called Aptana Studio 3. It's added a menu item to my context menu(if I right click I see an option "Aptana Studio"). How can I manually remove this from my menu?

---

I have searched high and low and can't find a way to remove the Aptana stuff from my Firefox. Perhaps it's because I'm on Firefox 4. What I have done is I've gone into

```
about:config
```

I then searched for Aptana and there are 3 items that are listed. I've attached a screenshot.

My question now is how can I remove these items because perhaps this will remove the option from my menu.
[image: about:config]

Comment: In which context menu do you see it? In file manager when you right click on any file or elsewhere? How did you install Aptana? Have you used standalone version or Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Strangely it's when I right click on a page using firefox then I see this option.I installed it as a stand alone. I would like to keep it on my machine just not have this menu item, it's above the View Source option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this context menu appears in Firefox, it seems most likely that Aptana installed a Firefox extension.

[This howto](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Uninstalling+the+debugger#Uninstallingthedebugger-TouninstallthedebuggerfromFirefox) describes uninstallation process.

Basically just go to `Tools > Add-ons` in Firefox. There you should find some Aptana related extension - it's probably called "Debugger". You can either disable or remove the extension - the resulting effect will be the same.

**Edit:** Aptana was added (automatically?) as Firebug's external editor. While editing about:config is an option, the "proper" way to edit external editors is through Firebug's "Configure Editor" window, which you can find in context menu as an extended option for the editor or through Firebug's main menu:

[image: Firebug Configure Editors]

Comment: i see the how to. for some reason there isn't that Debugger ext listed in my extentions. I'm on FF4. when i click this option is actually opens up Aptana Studio.

Comment: Is there any other Aptana related extension? Any extension which you don't know what it does? I don't think there's other way how Aptana could smuggle that menu entry into Firefox.

Comment: really strange. there is nothing that i don't know. extentions or add ons. so strange. i even disabled the ubuntu modification but it's the same. maybe i should just uninstall aptana completely.

Comment: That's really strange. There's no specific installation process during which Firefox profile would be modified - you just unpack the archive. It would take an additional configuration to modify Firefox.

Comment: i've added some information about. hopeing that i'm onto something.

Comment: I see, I didn't expect Aptana to install itself into Firebug's external editors. I've added info on how to properly edit Firebug's external editors, but since you've removed it via about:config, this probably doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 2):

My solutions to removing the Aptana Studio menu item out of my Firefox 4 context menu was to

1) go to about:config

2) search for Aptana

3) on each of the records(should be 3) right click and select reset

4) done.